# Center React-Multi-Carousel in Center mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-multi-carousel

I just started using [react-multi-carousel](https://openbase.com/js/react-multi-carousel) which I really like! Now I face an issue that I was not yet able to solve: If I use "Center mode" (`centerMode={true}`), I am not able to center the carousel. As soon as I change the surrounding div to `display: flex; justify-content: center;`, the carousel disappears or gets really small. It seems that the carousel in this mode calculates the available space within the surrounding container and uses the information for the rendering. At the same time, the flex wants to know, how much space the carousel occupies for centering. This is causing problems for me. This is only relevant for big screens where all items of the carousel are visible at once - in this case, I would like to have it centered. Does anyone know if and how it is possible to do that?

Here is an [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-grothendieck-pqh36r?file=/src/App.js) - Please let me know if you can not open it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you bring a minimal reproducible code for us to test?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I added a simple example to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for providing a minimal reproducible example,

For using `display: flex`, you should have a container that has the flexbox style. (for more details click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp))

you can see that there is no difference between `good` and `badStyle` if you use the following to define it:

```
const badStyle = {
    display: "block",
    justifyContent: "center"
};
```